# Playing video on TextureView

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming

In the documentation of Android [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) it says that you can use a TextureView to play video: 
But I cant seem to find any example of how to do this. Does anyone know?

I need to use a `textureView` because I want to animate the video. I want to play a video in .3gp/.mp4 format, not video from the Camera :)

Any help would be appreciated..

UPDATE:

Solution is posted as a community wiki answer

Comment: did you turn on hardware acel on the activity?

Comment: I just set it in the Manifest :)

Comment: Would you have any idea why onSurfaceTextureAvailable never called?

Comment: Also. you can always check http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java for how Google did the regular VideoView.

Comment: @Edison and if you actually looked at the source you would see they use a SurfaceView, not a TextureView.  Question asks for TextureView.

Comment: @David, you can simply switch out the callbacks. Vine on Android right now uses the VideoView that inherits from TextureView. (I may open source it at one point soon)

Comment: @Edison provided you know to make a new Surface over the TextureView -- which the VideoView doesn't show how to do.

Comment: @Edison I trying play auto video in list view like vine. I created a custom texture view, which is working fine if i use it as a single view in an activity. However if i use it as an item view in list view - SurfaceTextureListener never gets called and surface texture is always null. Therefore no video are played. Can you shed some light, on how can i fix this. https://raw.github.com/ash-gupta/MyTestVideoView/master/MyTestVideoView

Comment: @aNoviceGuy is the view visible? Your view looks fine (though I did not test it). Auto play just need you to do start in onPrepared.

Comment: @Edison - Like i said - it works when i use it as a single view in an activity. But When i am using it in a list item - it is not showing anything.I set the listview item background to white , and that is what comes up, items with with white color only, no video or image.
I checked that my view is visible but still nothing shows up :( 
Mediaplayer on prepare is calling start. 
In my adapter get view - i am just doing 
holder.videoView.setVideoPath("any mp4 url");
holder.videoView.start();

Comment: @Zelleriation you should post your solution as an answer. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:
(solution by the question author, that he posted as an update  in the question)

```
Public class MediaPlayerDemo_Video extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {


 private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

 private TextureView mPreview;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

      super.onCreate(icicle);

      mPreview = new TextureView(this);
      mPreview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

      extras = getIntent().getExtras();

      setContentView(mPreview);
 }

 @Override
 public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
 Surface s = new Surface(surface);

 try {
       mMediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
       mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");
       mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
       mMediaPlayer.prepare();
       mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
       mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
       mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
       mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
       mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       mMediaPlayer.start();
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

And animating it works really well.

Comment: Using TextureView instead of SurfaceView solved flickering problem on video playback. Thanks!

Comment: what is R.id.surface & extras in the onCreate?

Comment: @PranoyC The TextureView, apparently.

Comment: Don't forget to release the surface

Comment: Excellent, small point, the @Override property is missing from the onSurfuceTextureAvailable function

Comment: Thanks @JonDunn.  Please note that the `@Override` annotation is not required. Nonetheless It helps to prevent errors since If a method marked with @Override fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error, that is why it is a good style practice. I will edit the post

Comment: Implement these if requires 

MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener, 
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, 
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, 
MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and solved it with a `TextureView`. I found `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` very useful, if this helps anyone. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX%28float%29

However if you are only targeting API 16+:

```
mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

should do it:)

Comment: you are really lazy to help

Answer (score -2):

Your  `setContentView(mPreview);` needs to be called before the

```
mPreview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```

Comment: here you answer the question not to correct the answer.. use comment for correcting the it.