# Android VideoView not playing after setRotation()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I've found that after calling `setRotation()` on a VideoView, that VideoView no longer plays. No errors are thrown by the Android runtime, and the VideoView correctly determines its crop dimensions but only shows as a solid black box.

Is this a known limitation? If so is there another way to rotate VideoViews? I'm using API level 16.

**Edit:** The video plays audio, but no video. Perhaps the underlying SurfaceView isn't being repositioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself in case it helps somebody later, this is a known limitation of VideoView. Quote from [this Android graphics blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html):

> Because a SurfaceView’s content does not live in the application’s window, it cannot be transformed (moved, scaled, rotated) efficiently. This makes it difficult to use a SurfaceView inside a ListView or a ScrollView. SurfaceView also cannot interact properly with some features of the UI toolkit such as fading edges or View.setAlpha().

The only solution I could find was to replace the VideoView with the newly-introduced [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), which is only available in API level 14 and above. From what I read it is not currently available in the compatibility library. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview) has an example of how to use a TextureView to play video, it's pretty easy and all you lose is the convenience of a VideoView wrapping a MediaPlayer for you.