# Android SurfaceView Video Overlap

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

In my app, I'm displaying local videos using a SurfaceView. However, I noticed a strange (rare) bug when switching between videos: they both overlap.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot]

Sometimes the old video (top black video) stays still and sometimes it still continues playing. (with no audio)

How do I fix this?
I was previously using a VideoView and still had this issue. My VideoFragment is recreated everytime I open a new video. I tried releasing the video in the onPause() of the fragment but still no luck.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    if (player != null && Video.getDownloaded())
    {
        if(player.isPlaying())
            player.stop();

        controller.hide();
        player.release();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance,

~Pkmmte Xeleon

Comment: How are you switching between the videos? Do you have only one `SurfaceView` (right answer) or are you trying to have more than one `SurfaceView` (wrong answer)?

Comment: I initialize a new Fragment to replace the current one. I only have one SurfaceView.

Comment: Since only one `SurfaceView` cannot overlap itself, clearly you must have more than one. Are you swapping fragments, each of which having a `SurfaceView`?

Comment: Yes, I'm swapping fragments with each having a SurfaceView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, a `SurfaceView` is a weird "widget". Treat them carefully.

Try reorganizing your UI to have a single `SurfaceView` (or `VideoView` if you roll back to that). For example, that could be fixed below your action bar tabs, with the rest of your content inside a fragment beneath it. On a tab change, update the video and replace the main fragment.

Or, if you are only supporting API Level 14+, try `TextureView` instead.

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion seems to have worked!
However, I'd like to give TextureView a try. I haven't heard of it until now but I can't find an equivalent for mMediaPlayer.setSurface(). =/
(I have a SurfaceTexture now rather than a Surface or SurfaceHolder)

Comment: @Pkmmte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview https://gist.github.com/kswlee/5627632 http://pastebin.com/NDkCdh5t

Comment: @CommonsWare hello, In my case I am playing Video as an Live Wallpaper, and over that in app playing Video in Fragment...so here before to appear video fragment it show BG(live wallpaper) for a moment then it start video...any suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

I use a surfaceView as the surface for video or draw something on the surface.
And when I switch the Activity very quickly, e.g. switch to Activity B and switch back very quickly, there are two surface overlap.

dumpsys SurfaceFlinger,there are two surfaceview in the output.

I try to modify the surfaceflinger, when the destroy surface called, evenif it is detached from layerbase, also destroy it.

And this issue dispeared.