# how to implement crop, stretch and fit to screen functionality on surface view for playing video

Tags: android

I have to implement crop,stretch and fit to screen functionality on video player in android .I am using surface view for playing video,  how can I achieve this functionality?!!

Comment: If you can target 4 and above, you can use TextureView to do some cropping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview

Comment: Yes I can use textureview but I am not clear how to stretch and crop video, if you have some piece of code please post