# Videoview Resize Not Working while using DraggablePanel Library Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement drag layout like youtube, for playing video in my applicaiton.
I took the help from [DraggablePanel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) library in Github. It works fine.
My application is for above 4.0 .

When i try to drag the video it do not scale  properly. Video is getting cut, when dragged/minimized to bottom.

Can you please help me how to resize the video when dragged ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that. I am facing the same problem, the video is not scaling properly.

Comment: yes i got the solution

Comment: hi @Divya , please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. User TextureView instead of SurfaceView or VideoView. SurfaceView does not support animations. Check this link if you want to know how to use textureView for playing video : [Playing video on TextureView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview)