# How to use TextureView to load and play video inside a RecyclerView from URL

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-recyclerview

I have a `ReclyclerView` as a list of Video.

How can I use `TextureViews` to load and play these videos? (video source form URLs)

If `TextureView` can not do it, please help know what is helpful on my case?

Comment: Someone already asked almost the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview

Comment: Thanks Sahli, but I need to play a video in a listview or a recyclerview as an list item.